# Removing the [''] format from a file

Tags: python, renaming, mutagen

I have to rip my cd library in Flac to archive them and long story short the filename when ripped doesn't include the track number, which is throwing off the playlist order when played on my audio player.

To save the trouble to rename them manually I wrote this morning a little script:

```
import os
from mutagen.flac import FLAC

chemin= r'E:\CD\CdName'

for titre in os.listdir(chemin):
    track= FLAC(os.path.join(chemin, titre))
    tracknumber = track.tags["tracknumber"]
    tracktitle= track.tags["title"]
    newtitle= str(tracknumber) + " " + str(tracktitle)
    os.rename(os.path.join(chemin,titre),os.path.join(chemin,str(newtitle)))
```

Sorry it's not the cleanest code, I am still a newbie in python.

It works fine for its purpose except that it has the format ['text'] in the track title which results in something like this ['01']  ['TrackName'] for the filename which is not convenient.

As a consequence I was wondering if there was a possibility to remove this unwanted formating in the track name.

Comment: what is the convenient name for you? can you post what you want as output?

Comment: I'm assuming that both `tracknumber` and `tracktitle` are returning lists and calling `str` on them simply wraps the brackets in quotes. make `newtitle` this -----> `newtitle = ' '.join([tracknumber.pop(), tracktitle.pop()])`, this assume the title is always the only item in that list however

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was exactly what I was looking for! I didn't know it was possible to do so.
Otherwise I guess it should be the only item on the list given that those are extracted from the track's metadatas, and I cannot think on the moment of a possibility of several items in a track name for example.

Answer (score 0):

Simply just replace the strings.

```
tracktitle = "['01'] ['TrackName']"
tracktitle = tracktitle.replace("[","").replace("]","")
tracktitle = tracktitle.replace("'", "")
```

This will output "01 TrackName"

Edit:
Edited to suit comments

```
tracktitle = "['01'] ['TrackName']"
tracktitle = tracktitle.replace("'] ['", " ")
tracktitle = tracktitle[2:]
tracktitle = tracktitle[0:-2]
```

Comment: Thank you Polymer, I considered this way but I wanted to keep these caracters in case they were embeded in the song, for example "Her's song"

Comment: Just made it more specific, try it now

Comment: Thanks a lot Polymer, I went with Dmitry solution as it is more compact with a line of code instead of 4, this being said I appreciate your input as well!

Answer (score 0):

As the problem is resolved thanks to you all, I thought it may interest people in the same case to have this script:

```
import os
from mutagen.flac import FLAC

chemin= r'C:\XXXXX' #your path here

for titre in os.listdir(chemin):
    track= FLAC(os.path.join(chemin, titre))
    tracknumber = track.tags["tracknumber"]
    tracktitle= track.tags["title"]
    newtitle= " - ".join([tracknumber.pop(),tracktitle.pop()])+".flac"
    newtitle = newtitle.replace("?","")
    os.rename(os.path.join(chemin,titre),os.path.join(chemin,str(newtitle)))
```

ps: I made a small edit to remove the problem with the question mark which is not compatible with file format